# Change textview color in listview from button that is not in the ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

How do you change the textcolor in a listview from a button that is not in the ListView? I have a button

```
tvbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
ListView tv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tvlist);
TextView n = (TextView)[MY ISSUE IS RIGHT HERE, I NEED THE VIEW IN THE LISTVIEW AND I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO GET IT].findViewById(R.id.x);
n.setTextColor(WHATEVERCOLOR);
}});
```

I pull data from sqlite here
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = controller.getReadableDatabase();

```
    String query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM blah";
    final Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    tv.setAdapter(new TVAdapter(context, cursor, 0));
```

Here is my TVAdapter

```
private static final class TVAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    MyTVAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.tvview, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.x1);
        TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.x);
        n.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("blahsds")));

        loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        loader.displayImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("blahsblahs")),iv, op);
    }

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling the adapter not the listview

```
    private static final class TVAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        private int color = 0xFF000000; // default
        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        MyTVAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
            super(context, cursor, flags);

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.tvview, parent, false);
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.x1);
            TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.x);
            n.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("blahsds")));
            n.setTextColor(color);

            loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
            loader.displayImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("blahsblahs")),iv, op);
        }

        public int getColor() {
            return color;
        }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
}
```

just call `adapter.setColor(0xFFFF0000);` for example